# Django 1.7 app config ImportError: No module named appname.apps

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I'm trying to setup a custom application configuration for one of my Django app called 'articles' following the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/, but I keep getting `ImportError: No module named articles.apps` when execute `./manage.py check` (or any other management command such as `./manage.py runserver`)

This is a tree of the project

```
projectname
    ├── apps
    │   ├── articles
    │   │   ├── admin.py
    │   │   ├── apps.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── migrations
    │   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── models.py
    │   │   ├── templates
    │   │   │   └── articles
    │   │   ├── templatetags
    │   │   │   ├── articles_tags.py
    │   │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── tests.py
    │   │   ├── urls.py
    │   │   └── views.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
```

installed app in **settings.py**:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'grappelli',
  'django.contrib.admin', 
  'django.contrib.auth', 
  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
  'django.contrib.sessions', 
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'django.contrib.humanize', 
  'grappelli.dashboard', 
  'mptt', 
  'sekizai', 
  'pytils', 
  'sorl.thumbnail',
  'sefaro.apps.utils', 
  'sefaro.apps.seo', 
  'sefaro.apps.staticpages', 
  'sefaro.apps.statictext', 
  'sefaro.apps.usersettings', 
  'sefaro.apps.navigation', 
  'sefaro.apps.slideshow',
  'sefaro.apps.articles', 
)
```

Contents of `articles/__init__.py`:

```
# articles/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig'
```

Contents of `articles/apps.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class ArticlesConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'articles'
    verbose_name = _(u'Articles')
```

And I have `'projectname.apps.articles'` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`

Just to ensure that I really have all these files and haven't messed up with paths

```
>>> from projectname.apps.articles.apps import ArticlesConfig
>>> ArticlesConfig
<class 'projectname.apps.articles.apps.ArticlesConfig'>
```

Everything imports just fine...

But:

```
(vagrant)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:~/django$ ./manage.py check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/vagrant/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/vagrant/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/vagrant/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named articles.apps
```

Comment: Can you show your INSTALLED_APPS setting?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'grappelli.dashboard',
    'mptt',
    'sekizai',
    'pytils',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'sefaro.apps.utils',
    'sefaro.apps.seo',
    'sefaro.apps.staticpages',
    'sefaro.apps.statictext',
    'sefaro.apps.usersettings',
    'sefaro.apps.navigation',
    'sefaro.apps.slideshow',
    'sefaro.apps.articles',
)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the specific Django project structure (all applications are located in `projectname/apps/` module) the **full path** including the project name should be used.

As the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name says:

> AppConfig.name
>
> Full Python path to the application, e.g. 'django.contrib.admin'.

So it should be:

```
# articles/apps.py:
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class ArticlesConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'projectname.apps.articles'
    verbose_name = _(u'Articles')
```

and

```
# articles/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'projectname.apps.articles.apps.ArticlesConfig'
```

Comment: providing the projectname in the name config did it for me

Answer (score 1):

The name attribute in the app configuration should be same as what we give in the installed apps.

Also `default_app_config` should give the correct path to your custom configuration like,

```
default_app_config = 'projectname.apps.articles.apps.ArticlesConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be focused in your **articles/__init__.py** file.

I mean... In the documentation says:

*Of course, you can also tell your users to put 'rock_n_roll.apps.RockNRollConfig' in their INSTALLED_APPS setting.*

You tried to delete the "default_app_config" statement and only getting your **articles.apps.ArticlesConfig** in your INSTALLED_APPS?

I say that because the docs says:

*That will cause RockNRollConfig to be used when INSTALLED_APPS just contains 'rock_n_roll'.*

In the case to have a default_apps_config declared in **articles/__init__.py**, in your INSTALLED_APPS it's only necessary:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ( 'grappelli', 'django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'django.contrib.humanize', 'grappelli.dashboard', 'mptt', 'sekizai', 'pytils', 'sorl.thumbnail', 'sefaro.apps.utils', 'sefaro.apps.seo', 'sefaro.apps.staticpages', 'sefaro.apps.statictext', 'sefaro.apps.usersettings', 'sefaro.apps.navigation', 'sefaro.apps.slideshow', 'articles', )
```

Maybe i'm wrong but I would try that :) Tell me if you need more help.

Comment: I tried to put `'articles'`, `'sefaro.articles.apps.ArticlesConfig'` in my INSTALLED_APPS, but no luck :(
The only correct variant which actually works is 'sefaro.apps.articles', but only if to comment out the `default_app_config` in `articles/__init__.py` (so no custom configuration is enabled)
I'll try to reload my vagrant box and keep my fingers crossed...

Comment: Reloading my Vagrant box did not help

Comment: Seems you solved your problem then :) I learned too how to fix that kind of issues. Thanks very much!